# I want to use the applications url_helpers in engines view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an engine.

I am overriding that engines view in the hosting application.
In those overridden views I want to use the applications url_helpers.

So far this works:

```
=link_to 'Create Checklist', Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_checklist_path, class: 'btn btn-success center-block'
```

But it is very inconvenient to reference Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Is there a way to shortcut it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
=link_to 'Create Checklist', main_app.new_checklist_path, class: 'btn btn-success center-block'

=link_to 'Create Checklist In Engine', myengine.engine_resource_path, class: 'btn btn-success center-block'
```